# How to add linebreak inside html.Div returned from a callback in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am returning a html.Div from a callback function but wondering how to add line breaks to it. The '\n' don't seem to be working. My callback function sends an SQL query and stores query results into a pandas data frame.

Below is what I'm trying to return from the callback:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-table1', component_property='children'),
    [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('faculty-name', 'value')]
)
def update_output_div(clicks, input_value):

...
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor, columns=cursor.column_names)

# name = df['faculty_name'].to_string()
        name = df['faculty_name'].values[0]
        position = df['position'].values[0]
        email = df['email'].values[0]

  return html.Div(
            children=[
                html.H6(
                    children=f"Name: {name}, \n Position: {position} \n Email: {email}",
                    style={'textAlign':'left', 'color': colors['text'], 'margin-left': '20px', 'font-size': '16px'}
            )])
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```py
  h6_styles = {
    'textAlign':'left', 
    'color': colors['text'], 
    'margin-left': '20px', 
    'font-size': '16px'
  }
  return html.Div(
    children=[
      html.H6(
        children=f"Name: {name}",
        style=h6_styles,
      ),
      html.H6(
        children=f"Position: {position}",
        style=h6_styles,
      ),
      html.H6(
        children=f"Email: {email}",
        style=h6_styles,
      )
    ]
  )
```